# Raspberry Pi and ESP32 - Fast real-time wifi connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, protocols, esp32

What protocol shall i suse for best realtime communication from Raspberry pi to ESP32.

I'm doing some computation on R pi (FFT on signals) and the result shall be sent every 10ms to ESP32.
Esp32 puts the result to LED display and stepper motor.
Raspberry pi is on ethernet and ESP32 on wifi (LAN, home network)
I need to transfer 10 bytes of data every 10ms, but the time delay and frequency response shall be very small. What protocol shall i use? I think MQTT is to slow? Any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Anything involves a wireless communication can't be trusted in terms of consistent package delivery with low latency. I don't think you can achieve your 10ms goal for every package with WiFi. There's too many external factors.

Having said that, from your question, I understand you make a measurement/calculation on ESP32 and want to use it somewhere else with low latency. Since an outdated measurement/calculation is redundant, you need to implement a datagram. If your problem definition is suitable to skip a package every now and then, I would use UDP packets. If it arrives in 10ms with no complication, there's no problem with both UDP or TCP. But when it doesn't, UDP will just ignore the fault and send the next data package while TCP will try to deliver it even after 10ms.

Also please be aware that even in TCP, you can have some amount of undelivered packages. (packet loss)

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the limits of what a WiFi connection can do. Low latency, low jitter data transfers are certainly not guaranteed. If the WiFi channel is even mildly utilized, collisions will introduce delays of several tens or hundreds of milliseconds. The frequency of those delays depends directly on channel utilization. As Bora said, raw UDP datagrams are your best bet. You have to build into the protocol a mechanism to recover from samples which are lost or arrive to late to be useful. All in all, this is not a trivial task, so good luck :)